# Convert H M S to hh:mm in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that consists of times in the following format:

```
Time 
9H 30M 0S
10H 0M 0S
10H 30M 0S
```

I want to convert this to

```
Time
9:30
10:00
10:30
```

I don't how to do this. Can anyone help me out?

Edit:

Suppose this is stored in a df, then I used:

```
X <- X %>%
  mutate(hour = hour(Time),
         minute = minute(Time)) %>%
  unite(time, hour, minute, sep = ":")
```

Which gave me the output that I wanted.

Yet, I am wondering whether there is a quicker way to obtain the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert it to `POSIXct` and use `format` for the desired output.

```
format(as.POSIXct(x$Time, format="%HH %MM %SS"), "%H:%M")
#[1] "09:30" "10:00" "10:30"
```

Data:

```
x <- data.frame(Time = c("9H 30M 0S", "10H 0M 0S", "10H 30M 0S"))
```